# Why HttpContext.Current is not null in async/await with ConfigureAwait

Tags: c#, async-await, configureawait

I have a library async function called from controller. I expected HttpContext.Current to be null after await with ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere, but in controller it is not null. Can somebody explain why?

```
//in libraby
public class MyClass
{
    public async Task WaitAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // null, OK
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var class1 = new MyClass();
        await class1.WaitAsync();

        var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // not null, WHY???

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: `await class1.WaitAsync();`, there is no `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, so why do you expect the HttpContext to be null?

Comment: @KevinGosse because all code after await executes in a thread from thread pool. I've checked ManagedThreadId is the same.

Comment: ConfigureAwait(false) acts only till the end of the method calls it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though it is much more complex than that, you can picture `await` as a kind of `ContinueWith`. So if you write for instance:

```
DoSomeStuff();
await WaitAsync()
DoMoreStuff();
```

It is rewritten to:

```
DoSomeStuff();
WaitAsync().ContinueWith(_ => DoMoreStuff());
```

`.ConfigureAwait` sets the context in which the continuation will execute. With `ConfigureAwait(true)` (the default), the continuation will execute in the same context as the caller. With `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the continuation will execute in the default invariant context, on the threadpool.
With our previous simplification, let's imagine `ConfigureAwait(true)` will be rewritten to `ContinueWithSameContext` and `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `ContinueWithThreadPool`.

Now what happens if we have nested methods? For instance, your code:

```
public async Task WaitAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // null, OK
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var class1 = new MyClass();
    await class1.WaitAsync();

    var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // not null, WHY???

    return View("Index");
}
```

This is rewritten too:

```
public Task WaitAsync()
{
    return Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .ContinueWithThreadPool(_ => 
        {
            var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // null, OK
        });
}        

public Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var class1 = new MyClass();
    return class1.WaitAsync().ContinueWithSameContext(_ =>
    {
        var httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; // not null, WHY???

        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

Rewritten this way, you see that the continuation of `WaitAsync` will run on the same context as `Task<ActionResult> Index()`, explaining why the HttpContext isn't null.