# Why is System.Web.HttpContext.Current null after awaiting an async method in a controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, one of my `Controller` action methods invokes some code that relies on getting information from the current `HttpContext`. That code is not part of my `Controller`, so it can't use `Controller.HttpContext` - instead it uses `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`. (I know that's a bad idea, but I'm not in a position to change that).

This was all working until I added an `await` to my `Controller` action method. Now, when I subsequently invoke the code that uses `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` it fails because `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

I did some reading and found something that said that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is only set on a the thread that's processing a web request. That makes sense. However, I'm surprised that simply using `await` is enough to switch to a different thread.

My understanding is that using `await` without `ConfigureAwait(false)` (as in `var result = await myTask;`) ensures that the code following the `await` is invoked using the `SynchronizationContext` in effect prior to the `await`.

I mentally equated this with "running on the same thread" - that is, the code after the `await` would run on the same thread as the code before the `await` (even though the `Task` being awaited might be executed on a different thread). Turns out that's not true - the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` is different before and after the `await`.

Oddly, the behaviour I'm seeing is the *opposite* of what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080787/why-httpcontext-current-is-not-null-in-async-await-with-configureawait).

I'm confused - can anyone shed any light on whether (a) I should expect `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` to be null after any `await` call, and (b) whether there's any way to make the code after the `await` resume on the same thread so that it's *not* null?

Comment: .NET Framework or Core?

Comment: @Flydog57: .NET Framework

Comment: Perhaps this can shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839382/4000335

Comment: @kshkarin: The does support the idea that there's no guarantee we'll end up back on the same thread. However I found another link that addresses my specific problem - I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384253/98422) on a similar question. Apparently this behaviour was caused by the "quirks mode" of ASP.NET. :-(

Adding the following to my `web.config` fixed the problem by ensuring that the code after the `await` was executed on the same thread, and so `HttpContext.Current` was non-null.

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
```

Comment: What runtime are you using?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: the project was originally for ASP.NET v4 (or perhaps earlier) and is now using ASP.NET v4.5 or later. Because the project was upgraded rather than created afresh, the `<httpruntime targetFramework="4.5" />` entry wasn't added to the web.config. That or the entry in my answer both fix the issue I was having.